# Error during installation of kurento-media-server E: Failed to fetch 403 Forbidden

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates

I am installing kurento-media-server from [official guide](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installation.html#local-installation) for Ubuntu in Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I executed these commands first:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5AFA7A83

source /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release 2>/dev/null || source /etc/lsb-release

sudo tee "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list" >/dev/null <<EOF
# Kurento Media Server - Release packages
deb [arch=amd64,trusted=yes] http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.15.0 $DISTRIB_CODENAME focal kms6
EOF
```

After that this happened :

```
root@DESKTOP-PRK1GBK:~# sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.218.106.43 80]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.218.106.43 80]
E: The repository 'http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Theses are the contents of `kurento.list` file:

```
root@DESKTOP-PRK1GBK:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
# Kurento Media Server - Release packages
deb [arch=amd64,trusted=yes] http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal kms6
```

I have tried to use `--allow-insecure-repositories` and this is the output:

```
root@DESKTOP-PRK1GBK:~# sudo apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Ign:5 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal Release
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all Packages
Ign:9 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:11 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all Packages
Ign:9 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:11 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all Packages
Ign:9 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:11 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all Packages
Ign:9 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:11 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all Packages
Ign:9 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:11 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Ign:7 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all Packages
Ign:9 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:11 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err:7 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.218.105.226 80]
Ign:8 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all Packages
Ign:9 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 Translation-en
Ign:10 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 all c-n-f Metadata
Ign:11 http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal/kms6 amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0 focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.openvidu.io/6.10.0/dists/focal/kms6/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.218.105.226 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: You're trying to install software from a repository that does not exist. To prove it check the link in a web browser. If you can't manually download a package and manually install it then you can't install the same package with apt either.

Comment: i have checked it in the browser here's the XML it returns : `<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>6E4E8EE4A60746B6</RequestId>
<HostId>SBgkP5F0GB3TM/gTpjJ5u8JaaT3I4pTa8ypICi+CfOpPIEn7WtCq1sifcgOZ9f9UU4QeIe/wZjg=</HostId>
</Error>`

Comment: The repository doesn't exist. If it did exist you would see an index page with a link on it to download the software manually.

Comment: I must install kurento-media-server. Is there any other method i could try? Maybe i should not use WSL and install the whole OS in which case which distro or version should i use?

Comment: https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server - for Debian-based systems